# Azure Web App with Azure SingnalR - Private endpoints changes wss to https and throws CORS erros

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side, azure-webapps, azure-signalr

I deployed a sample MS Blazor server application in Azure Web App and Ref. an Azure SignalR service as well from thihs Web App.

1st I made the Azure SignalR as public as below.

[image]

My Web App is able to connect to the Azure SignalR. Ref. below track from browser.

> WebSocket connected to
> ***wss://syncfusionblazorservice.service.signalr.n**e*t/client/?hub=componenthub&asrs.op=%2F_blazor&negotiateVersion=1&asrs_request_id=4Vy5v2IfAAA%3D&id=bDIxMkP-NT2nQkia9YeDfA48cf3bb91&access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IkNwTVpMbWxJV01sUG9xWVR0am9xNXFuNHNQM1JEcVpJTHdjQW1MWm43MFU9IiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.eyJuYmYiOjE2NDc1MTA0MzYsImV4cCI6MTY0NzUxNDAzNiwiaWF0IjoxNjQ3NTEwNDM2LCJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL3N5bmNmdXNpb25ibGF6b3JzZXJ2aWNlLnNlcnZpY2Uuc2lnbmFsci5uZXQvY2xpZW50Lz9odWI9Y29tcG9uZW50aHViIn0.yHlIWpE3_qX03v5T26ZuXdUXWy4Zx10J07HvAActqeE.

Please notice as above sucessful connection used a wss:// URL.

later I disabled the public access to Azure SignalR and tried to access it using an azure Private Endpoint. Now Ref. below browser track which is throwing error

> *Access to fetch at '**https://syncfusionblazorservice.service.signalr.net**/client/negotiate?hub=componenthub&asrs.op=%2F_blazor&negotiateVersion=1&asrs_request_id=EIgI9WEfAAA%3D'
> from origin 'https://epdone.azurewebsites.net' has been blocked by
> CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control
> check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
> requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the
> request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.*

2 issues are here.

1. The wss:// URL of azure signalr has been Ref. wrongly as https://
2. As of above issue CORS error also throwing

My question is that why private endpoint is trying to access signalR URL as https://, where once public access has enablded, its taking the correct wss:// url?

Answer (score 0):

## Newest

When you disabled the public network in azure signalr service, I guess you may not configure anything in your networing(azure app service side). So your web app still access the signalr service with public IP, that why you get 403 error code.

**You can follow the steps in below blogs.**

[Securing Azure SignalR +Azure App Service - Part 2](https://dev.to/jayendran/securing-azure-signalr-azure-app-service-part-2-2mf1)

---

## Previous

**You can try below steps to resolve this issue, just simply add the origin URL to the Azure Web App.**

1. Open your azure portal, find the Azure Web Site.
2. Navigate to CORS.
3. Remove “*”
4. Add the origin URL, for example, `https://epdone.azurewebsites.net`.
5. Make sure Enabled Access-Control-Allow-Credentials is checked.

Follow the steps above to see if that resolves your issue.

#### To answer your doubts:

> My question is that why private endpoint is trying to access signalR URL as https://, where once public access has enablded, its taking the correct wss:// url?

CORS is a mechanism that uses additional HTTP headers to tell browsers to give a web application running at one origin, access to selected resources from a different origin. A web app executes a cross-origin HTTP request when it requests a resource that has a different origin (domain, **protocol**, or port) from its own.

***So you see that the error message was sent to us by CORS.***

Comment: @JaishMathews Which version of azure signalr sdk you use ?

Comment: Thanks. Eventhough I tried this after the comment and noticed that issue still exists, this approach logically won't work as of below facts. 1. CORS throwing as of  wss:// suddenly changed to https:// on enabling private end point . This issue not happens just making Azure SignalR as public. 2. Also CORS to be defined on target side telling what source/origin it can accept and it shouldn't be defined on request side. Here Web App is on request side.

Comment: The NuGet Microsoft.Azure.SignalR version 1.13.0

Comment: @JaishMathews This issue seems you missed something in your app service, I will update my answer.

Comment: For clarifying the quote "When you disabled the public network in azure signalr service, I guess you may not configure anything in your networing(azure app service side)"....     
I have a created private endpoint subnect under the same VNet where Azure Web App resides. This private endpoint has been assigned to Azure SignalR as private access. Now this private endpoint meant to provde communication, but its not....Anyway I will check the link youe shared again to notice any gaps here.

Comment: @JaishMathews Pls double check the setting in your azure web app and signalr service follow the blogs. It will help you solve the issue.

Comment: I Ref. the link shared. It has enabled the public access to SignalR service and then restricting using Access Control. I was asking an approach after disabling the public access to SignalR service. Once you disable the public access to SignalRs, a CORS error appearing as mentioned in my question.

Comment: @JaishMathews  After you disabling the public access to SignalR service, we know your signalR service can't be accessed in public network,  but your webapp still try to access your signalr service with public ip.

Comment: @JaishMathews https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/howto-private-endpoints  I understood you correctly, please read carefully the blog in the answer and this official documentation.